Non linear differential equation (Korteweg–De Vries) becomes unstable with time
I would like to solve the Korteweg-De Vries equation with the initial conditions U(x,0) = n(n+1)/cosh^2(x). However, my system becomes numerically unstable for n>1 (n is an integer), what could be the reason?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# Parameters
L = 40    # Length of the interval
N = 256   # Number of grid points
dx = L / N  # Spatial step size
x = np.linspace(-L/2, L/2, N)  # Discretized spatial domain
dt = 0.1  # Time step size
T = 20    # End time
n = 1     # Parameter n for the initial condition

# Initial condition u(x,0) = n*(n+1)/cosh^2(x)
u0 = (n * (n + 1)) / np.cosh(x)**2

# Function to compute derivatives according to the KdV equation
def derivs(t, u):
    # Periodic boundary conditions are applied using np.roll
    uxx = np.roll(u, -1) - 2 * u + np.roll(u, 1)  # Second derivative
    uxx /= dx**2
    uxxx = np.roll(uxx, -1) - np.roll(uxx, 1)  # Third derivative
    uxxx /= 2 * dx
    # KdV equation: time derivative of u
    return -6 * u * (np.roll(u, -1) - np.roll(u, 1)) / (2 * dx) - uxxx

# Solve the KdV equation using a 4th-order Runge-Kutta method
sol = solve_ivp(derivs, [0, T], u0, method='RK45', t_eval=np.arange(0, T, dt))

# Animation of the solution
plt.figure()
for i in range(len(sol.t)):
    plt.clf()  # Clear the previous plot
    plt.plot(x, sol.y[:, i])  # Plot the solution at time t[i]
    plt.title(f"Solution of the KdV equation at t={sol.t[i]:.1f}")
    plt.xlabel("x")  # Label for the x-axis
    plt.ylabel("u(x,t)")  # Label for the y-axis
    plt.ylim([-0.5, n*(n+1)+0.5])  # Set y-axis limits for better visualization
    plt.pause(0.1)  # Short pause to animate the plot

plt.show()  # Show the final plot window


(1) the signs of the 6 term and the third derivative should be opposite (probably positive for the third derivative). (2) Why not write the third derivative directly? See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

Thank you! I used finite difference and adjusted the grid points. The signs should be correct. However it works now

Your initial condition is wrong for a general n. It should be
u0 = (n * (n + 1)) / np.cosh( 0.5 * np.sqrt(2*n*(n+1.0)) * x ) ** 2

You still get tiny amounts of dispersion though.

Yes, these are also valid initial conditions, but not for my problem. The number of waves should increase with n.

But with your initial condition there is only one wave. Its amplitude just increases with n. Its width should diminish to compensate. Can you point us to a solution of the KdV equation with more than one wave?
